# Como criar uma matriz com alocação dinâmica e structs

Tags: c, matriz, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória

Eu sei criar uma matriz utilizando somente alocação dinâmica. Contudo, não estou conseguindo criar utilizando estruturas.

Tenho a seguinte struct:

```
struct matriz{
    int** elemento;
    int nlinhas;
    int ncolunas;
};
```

e usei typedef pra facilitar ficando assim:

```
typedef struct matriz Matriz;
```

Assim tentei implementar a seguinte função:

```
Matriz* inicializaMatriz(int nlinhas, int ncolunas){
    Matriz* mat;

    mat = (Matriz*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    mat->nlinhas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nlinhas);
    mat->ncolunas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ncolunas);

    return mat;
}
```

Entretanto, quando eu tento implementar essa outra função que irá atribuir valores a cada elemento da matriz:

```
void modificaElemento(Matriz* mat, int linha, int coluna, int elem){
    mat[linha][coluna]->elemento = elem;
}
```

Recebo a mensagem de que não é possivel(subscrited value is neither array nor pointer nor vector)

Com isso, gostaria de ajuda para conseguir criar uma matriz utilizando a estrutura já citada.

Comment: Se em sua struct Matriz `nlinhas` e `ncolunas` são campos int então as atribuições: `mat->nlinhas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nlinhas);` e `mat->ncolunas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ncolunas);` não fazem sentido.

Comment: mas eu n tenho que alocar memória para as linhas e para as colunas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua alocação não está correta em várias partes, e isto refere especificamente a função `inicializaMatriz`. Esta deve passar a ficar assim:

```
Matriz* inicializaMatriz(int nlinhas, int ncolunas){
    Matriz* mat = malloc(sizeof(Matriz)); //criar primeiro o elemento da estrutura
    mat->elemento = malloc(sizeof(int*) * nlinhas); //aloca a matriz dentro da estrutura
    mat->nlinhas = nlinhas; //coloca o numero de linhas dentro da estrutura
    mat->ncolunas = ncolunas; //coloca o numero de colunas dentro da estrutura

    //percorre cada linha com um for para criar as colunas
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nlinhas; ++i){
        mat->elemento[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * ncolunas);
    }

    return mat;
}
```

Anotei todas as diferenças com comentários. Atente como a criação do `mat->elemento` é com o `sizeof(int*)` e a das colunas é com `sizeof(int)`, que era um dos problemas que tinha anteriormente.

A parte de modificação também não está correta, pois o `elemento` é que é a matriz e não o `mat`. Altere para:

```
void modificaElemento(Matriz* mat, int linha, int coluna, int elem){
    mat->elemento[linha][coluna] = elem;
}
```

Com estas alterações já funciona, [como pode ver no Ideone](https://ideone.com/icVHEH).